# Remove inner array based on array key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array where I need to remove an item from the array.  I am looking to remove the whole subset array not just a value.  I am looking to do this be the subset array's key.  I have tried multiple attempts to remove this using loops and other array functions and searching through stack without success.

Here is an example of the array.

$array

```
Array ( 
    [key1] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 0 ) 
    [key2] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 1 ) 
    [key3] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 2 ) 
    [key4] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 3 ) 
    [key5] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 4 )
    [key6] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 5 ) 
    [key7] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 6 ) 
)
```

I am using php7

When I try loops it only removes key, and keeps the rest of the values.

I want to remove the key4 subarray and keep the rest intact.

Expected output:

```
Array ( 
    [key1] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 0 ) 
    [key2] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 1 ) 
    [key3] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 2 )  
    [key5] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 4 )
    [key6] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 5 ) 
    [key7] => Array ( [title] => Title [visible] => 1 [order] => 6 ) 
)
```

Comment: I've added php as a tag to this question to get the right eyeballs on it.

Comment: Please show your attempt where you say it removes the key but keeps the values.

Comment: Did you try `unset($array["key4"])`?

Comment: I'm very curious to what you have tried that removes the key but keeps the values below.

Comment: trincot... i did try unset, but was using it a loop that what was causing my problem

Comment: I just needed different set of eyes and thought process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove array base key here

```
$res= Array ( 
'key1' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title', 'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 0 ) ,
'key2' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title' ,'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 1 ) ,
'key3' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title' ,'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 2 ) ,
'key4' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title' ,'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 3 ) ,
'key5' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title' ,'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 4 ),
'key6' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title' ,'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 5 ) ,
'key7' => Array ( 'title' => 'Title' ,'visible' => 1 ,'order' => 6 ) ,
```

);

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "Before Array<br>";
print_r($res);
unset($res['key4']);
echo "After Array<br>";
print_r($res);
```

Output Here

Before Array

```
 Array( [key1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 0
    )

[key2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 1
    )

[key3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 2
    )

[key4] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 3
    )

[key5] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 4
    )

[key6] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 5
    ))

[key7] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 6
    ))
```

After Array

```
Array([key1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 0
    )

[key2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 1
    )

[key3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 2
    )

[key5] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 4
    )

[key6] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 5
    )

[key7] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [visible] => 1
        [order] => 6
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you... I must have been looking at this problem for 2 hours, and thought I had tried this.  But must have been one I missed.  Probably just needed a break, however as usual this great community comes through.